# Can we distinguish between a Martian sunset and a telluric sunset?

Tags: image-processing, analysis

Here is an image taken by Spirit. I get it from APOD. The sun is smaller and the atmosphere is kind of reddish. But under some weather circumstances on our earth, we may get a similar image, which I am not sure of.

My question is how to distinguish between them safely?

Can we get a definite answer?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about astronomy or image processing and too broad for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to guess with a success rate better than 50% by sampling the sky colour and checking the image for Earth-like features such as water reflections an buildings (which typically produce images with a lot of vertical edges).

However, I'd say it would be impossible to classify sunset images from Earth and Mars with 100% reliability (See [Why the Sunset Looks the Same on Mars as it Does in Beijing](http://gizmodo.com/why-the-sunset-looks-the-same-on-mars-as-it-does-in-bei-513190854), for example).

Comment: oops ......... The folks in charge of the tourism board in Beijing should use this as a selling point.

"Come visit beautiful Beijing, the closest thing to watching a Martian sunset!